# An automorphism of $A[X]$ inducing the identity on $ A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I have the following problem to work on.

"Let $A$ be a commutative entire ring and $X$ a variable over $A$. Let $a,b \in A$ and assume that $a$ is a unit in $A$. Show that the map $X \mapsto aX+b$ extends to a unique automorphism of $A[X]$ inducing the identity on $A$. What is the inverse automorphism?".

My question here, and in general in this type of problems, is how should understand the part "inducing the identity"? What exactly does "inducing" mean? Is this a similar meaning to when we say "an induced map"?

Comment: Is the original question in English, or have you translated it?

Comment: The original question is in English, from Lang's "Algebra" book, exercise 8 from chapter 4.

Answer (score 3):

A clearer formulation of the problem would be:

> Show that there exists a unique automorphism of $A[X]$ that is the identity on $A$ and such that $X$ is mapped to $aX+b$.